# Writing data from the RFID reader to excel file using RS232 and JAVA language

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying a very simple thing - grabbing a value from an RFID reader, and storing it in excel spreadsheet ,serial port used here is RS232.I am not able to write the data to the single cell .what could be the problem?
thank you.

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet spreadSheet = workbook.createSheet("sample");

try{
String info;
for(int rownum = 0; rownum <8;rownum++){
int cellnum = 0;
Row row = spreadSheet.createRow(rownum);
Cell  cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
for(int j=0;j<=3;j++){
char c =  (char) in.read();
String s = Integer.toHexString(c).toUpperCase();
info=  (s.length() == 1 ? "0" : "") + s;
cell.setcellvalue(info);
}}

System.out.print(info);
FileOutputStream iii=new    FileOutputStream("C:/Users/HK/Desktop/Rfid_read.xls");


workbook.write(iii);


}
```

Comment: Any code we can see ? Any error/exception thrown out ? Please be more specific.

Comment: Did you try to write anywhere else. For example txt file. ?

Comment: Yes i have tried in text file and i could write the data to it

Comment: i will post the code give me sometime